# String Arrays not working. Compiler not interacting

Tags: java, arrays

I was learning how to sort arrays with different types of value holders. I tried to sort an array with Strings, but it comes up with the error message, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at SortingArrays.main(SortingArrays.java:50)

There aren't any errors the compiler found, but it comes up with this. The array with numbers worked fine, but the strings didn't. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class SortingArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] aryNums;

        aryNums = new int[6];


        aryNums[0] = 7;
        aryNums[1] = 89;
        aryNums[2] = 45;
        aryNums[3] = 234;
        aryNums[4] = 2;
        aryNums[5] = 75;


        Arrays.sort(aryNums);

        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < aryNums.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(aryNums[i]);
        }


        String[] aryStrings;

        aryStrings = new String[5];


        aryStrings[0] = "I have no idea what I'm doing.";
        aryStrings[1] = "Should I know what I'm doing?";
        aryStrings[2] = "I guess not.";
        aryStrings[3] = "There's my boss.";
        aryStrings[4] = "Whoop, he's looking. Hide!";



        Arrays.sort(aryStrings);


        int x;

        for (x = 0; x < aryStrings.length; x++) {

            System.out.println(aryStrings[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You never reset `i` back to `0`.

Comment: Specifically, you're looping with `x` but indexing with `i` - which is why you should be declaring your indexers in the scope of the `for` loop instead of outside of it. This would then become a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting runtime exception. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you are trying to access array beyond its capacity with what its defined.

Problem is with this code:

```
for (x = 0; x < aryStrings.length; x++){
    System.out.println(aryStrings[i]);
                                  ^^
}
```

You are using `i` as index instead of `x`. Here `i` (after your print statements) would be 6 in your case and your array can hold 5 elements which start with 0 and ends with 5.

Answer (score 3):

At the very end of your program:

```
 System.out.println(aryStrings[i]);
```

i = 6, of course it out of bounds

What you need is:

```
System.out.println(aryStrings[x]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`i` after your first loop is 6.

so here

```
for (x = 0; x < aryStrings.length; x++){
        System.out.println(aryStrings[i]); // i here is 6 but there are 5 elements in aryStrings
    }
```

use `x` in this loop not `i`

Answer (score 1):

As other commenters have said, the problem is with your iterating variable.
But to completely avoid this problem, use a for-each loop.
As Joshua Bloch says in Effective Java, 2nd Edition (Item 46):

```
// The preferred idiom for iterating over collections and arrays
for (int aryNum : aryNums) {
   System.out.println(aryNum);
}
```

Or better in Java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(aryNums).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using i instead of x in the second print statement

Answer (score 0):

Change the index in `x`

```
   System.out.println(aryStrings[x]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have stated, by the time you reach your second loop, `i` is equal to a higher integer than your String array has indices.

Another way to fix your issue is to reset the value of `i`:

```
int x;
i = 0;//re-initialize    

for (x = 0; x < aryStrings.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(aryStrings[i]);
}
```

However, this defeats the purpose of your `x` variable.

As a rule of thumb, I'd keep your incrementer local to your loop to prevent problems like this arising:

```
//declare x in the loop
for (int x = 0; x < aryStrings.length; x++) {
    System.out.println(aryStrings[x]);
}
```